# Fluent Mappings

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

If you have a PK Column that is not generated in any way how is it mapped?

I assumed it would be something like:

```
Id(x => x.PKId).Column("PKId");
```

But I keep getting a:
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PKId', table 'X.dbo.DBTable; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .Column("PersonId")
  .GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

Taken from [here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping), paragraph "Id".